# Не выгружаются данные в EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Пытаюсь выгрузить таблицу из бд в datagrid, но возникает ошибка еще на этапе получения данных из БД
Собственно вот ошибка [image: Ошибка]

Подключение вроде есть, но данные вытащить не получается
[image: Строка подключения]
Модели Entity создавал вот по этому примеру - https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.2.php

Comment: Мало инфы. Покажи логи, название исключения или ещё что-то

Comment: @Маг-притворщик исключения как такого нет, единственная ошибка, которую нашел(И то только через отладчик) представлена на первом скрине

Comment: Попробуй удалить строчку datagr.DataContext. Я никогда не использовал это свойство, у меня всё работало.